# Difference in average of roll-up look up relationship

Tags: apex, soql, record-type

I got a requirement like to calculate average in account based on particular record type of case. My requirement is:

I have a field called ARP in account currency. I want to calculate overall average of ARP field in particular record type called customer order whether Case details either new or add-on.

So I'm trying write a trigger a trigger.

BARP field in case is a formula currency data type.In account also i had created Arpu name with currency(5,2).

> > But i am getting a difference in average.
>
> For sample scenario: 41.51 & 94.51
>
> Actual average for above scenario like 67.5.But, i am getting 139.51

```
trigger ForARPU on case (after delete, after insert) 
{  
Id recordTypeId = [Select Id From RecordType Where DeveloperName = 
                                              'Customer_Order'].Id;
List<Account> Accountstoupdate =new List<Account>();
List<Case> CaseIDs = new List<Case>();
for (Case s : Trigger.new)
{
    if(s.RecordTypeId == recordTypeId && s.Case_Details__c =='New 
                                  Subscription' || s.Case_Details__c =='Add On' ) 
    {
        CaseIDs.add(s);

    }
}
set<Id> setCaseIds = new set<Id>();
for(Case c : [SELECT Id,ARPU__c,accountId FROM Case WHERE Id IN :CaseIDs]){
    setCaseIds.add(c.AccountId);
}
List<Account> MList = [select Id,name,ARPU__c  from Account where id =:setCaseIds];
List <aggregateResult> groupedResults = [select sum(ARPU__c)aver from case where AccountId =: MList];
Decimal decimalRevenue = 0;
For(account a1: MList) {
if(groupedResults.size() > 0) 
{
    String str = '' + groupedResults[0].get('aver') ;
    decimalRevenue = Decimal.ValueOf(str) ;
    System.debug('decimalRevenue ::::: ' + decimalRevenue) ;
    a1.ARPU__c  = decimalRevenue;
    Accountstoupdate.add(a1);
}
}
if(Accountstoupdate.size()>0) {
    update Accountstoupdate;
}
}
```

Please can anyone tell me where did i went to wrong side

Answer (score 2):

Here if you don't get any results in query then you will get exception

```
Account M = [select Id,name,ARPU__c  from Account where id =:setCaseIds];
```

You should use it as

```
List<Account> MList = [select Id,name,ARPU__c  from Account where id =:setCaseIds];
```

also as you are passing set of Id so you will get multiple results so assign this to list.

Comment: Thanks It works fine.For sharing knowledge.But i didn't get actual average.There is a difference in average.@Tushar Sharma

Comment: @Pavantej you can post another question for that. If it solves your problem you can accept thhis answer.